# AWS educate starter account is no longer active

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Was working with aws-educate account. Had nearly 60 credits left. Today when i logged in, it said 
"your starter account is no longer active". Any reasons for this? I had 3 instances running on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to contact support.

You can contact them here: https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/contact-us/

Comment: Thanks for replying. This link leads us to main aws page. Cant login there with awseducate credentials.

Comment: Try this link: https://support.aws.amazon.com/#/contacts/aws-educate? Shouldn't require any login for that